# How to get research opportunities for software engineers?

Tags: mentoring

I have been working as a software engineer for a few months now. I want to do research and possibly publish a research paper in the field of computer science. Is it possible to do it while I am working as a software engineer at a company? If yes, how do I find a mentor or a professor to guide me for it.

Comment: What country are you in? Does your employer have a research department beyond just product research? What is your highest degree?

Comment: Also, this is easier if you actually register for the site.